# Visibility of classes in namespaces

Tags: f#

```
namespace Test

type Foo() =
    member this.HelloFoo = "Foo"
    member this.HelloFooBar = 
        let b = new Bar() // Why is Bar not visible here?
        this.HelloFoo + b.HelloBar 
type Bar() =
    member this.HelloBar = "Bar"
```

Why is Bar not visible in Foo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

F# declarations are processed top-to-bottom, so `Bar` has not been defined at the point it is referenced in `Foo`. You need to move the definition of `Bar` above `Foo`.

If your types are mutually dependent then you can use `and` to declare them both e.g.

```
type Foo =
...
and Bar =
...
```